# How can I place button tag in centre of a card in material Ui?

Tags: material-ui

There is only one button in the card and I want it to be exactly at the centre from vertical and centre from horizontal.
Actually having no content in my card is making it shrink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.card{height:200px;width:200px}
.card-body {
    padding: 1.25rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid #ccc
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff;
}
```

```html
<div class="card shadow">
  <div class="card-body">

    <div class="text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Center align</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
   <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

So, suppose this Div is the card and inside it button is the chlid. for making the button horizontally and vertically center just apply display Property [Flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), justify-content property [Center](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp) and align-items property to [Center](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp).

And the second issue "having no content in my card is making it shrink", it is because, having no content inside the card means there is no way that it could take some place in the browser as there is no child inside the card. but if you define a height and width to the card you will see that the card is not shirking.